# Помогите написать правильную хранимую процедуру для обновления таблицы

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

У меня есть две таблицы Departments и Users. Они соединены по полю DepId:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблицу Departments заранее заполнил данными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сделать Веб-форму, в которой я смогу делать операции CRUD с моей таблицей Users(набросал на скорую руку):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь вопрос, как написать хранимую процедуру, которая бы заполняла таблицу Users(поле DepId) по имеющейся информации NameDep(Это мои названия департаментов). Каскадное обновление стоит.

```
CREATE PROC hp
(
@FName varchar(20), @LName varchar(20), @NameDep nvarchar(20),@Event 
varchar(20),@DepId int
)
AS 
  BEGIN
  IF(@Event='Select')
  BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY FirstName ASC;
END

ELSE IF(@Event='Add')
BEGIN
  IF @NameDep = 'Дирекция' SET @DepId=1;
  INSERT INTO Users (FName,LName,DepId) VALUES(@FName,@LName,@DepId);
  IF @NameDep = 'Администрация' SET @DepId=2;
  INSERT INTO Users (FName,LName,DepId) VALUES(@FName,@LName,@DepId);
  IF @NameDep = 'Эксплуатация' SET @DepId=3;
  INSERT INTO Users (FName,LName,DepId) VALUES(@FName,@LName,@DepId);
END
END
```

Если это правильно, то дальше сделаю и Update по такому же принципу и Delete

Comment: Вот такого `IF @NameDep = 'Дирекция' SET @DepId=1;` в хранимках точно быть не должно.

Comment: @tym32167, за тем и обратился сюда, чтоб подсказали, как надо правильно сделать.

Comment: если советовать что то, то я бы на вашем месте отказался от хранимых процедур совсем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Зачем у вас `IF`, где в зависимости от `@NameDep` вы присваиваете `@DepId`?

Если у вас будет сотня департаментов, вы будете сотню IF'ов делать?

У вас есть таблица с департаментами=> вы можете сделать 1 изящный `SET`

```
SET @DepId=(SELECT DepId FROM Departaments where NameDep=@NameDep)
```

Вместо простыни `IF'ов`

2)Как я понимаю, вы одной процедурой хотите убить сразу 3-ех зайцев(Удаление, Добавление,Обновление)-это не правильно. Каждая процедура должна отвечать за конкретную логику.